# how to disable subversion in netbeans

Tags: svn, netbeans-7

I'm using NetBeans 7.0.1 on Windows and I have the following problem: my projects are versioned under SVN, but I'm using external SVN tools because I really don't like the built-in subversion client in netbeans, it is buggy and chaotic for me.

Now I'm trying to rename a file in my project, but it fails with SVN error

```
Subversion failed to move X:\***.html to: X:\***a.html
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: Cannot write to 'X:\***\.svn\tmp\text-base\indexa.html.svn-base': X:\***\.svn\tmp\text-base\indexa.html.svn-base (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Is there any way to completely disable subversion support in NetBeans? I don't use it and I don't want it.

I have googled a bit and found that uninstalling subversion plugin will help, but in this version of NetBeans subversion support is probably built-in, I don't see it in installed plugins and I can't find any setting disabling it. I also suspect NetBeans subversion of breaking my repository, even my regular client is now throwing errors.

Answer (score 29):

> in this version of NetBeans subversion support is probably built-in, I don't see it in installed plugins and I can't find any setting disabling it.

`Tools`-`Plugins` and in the `Installed` tab mark "Show details" checkbox, select Subversion and hit `Deactivate` or `Uninstall` button. The plugin will be deactivated/removed and you will be prompted to restart the IDE

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution to deactivate SVN project specific:

**Add the project folder to a list of unversioned folders**: 
config file: 
~/.netbeans/VERSION/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/versioning.properties

Add a line: 
unversionedFolders=FULL_PATH_TO_PROJECT_FOLDER

After IDE restart that project should not be considered versioned any more

[Source](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-42506.html)

Answer (score 1):

The NetBeans provides the ability to disconnect specific folders from Versioning under the options menus. This allows you to use the built in support for some projects and disable support in others. Be aware that you can only select folders which already are SVN managed.

[image]

This likely changes the same file as @Satya Prakash's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19333938/4252741) but through the GUI.